# What is the difference in the meanings of the sentences "Would you like some coffee?" and "Do you want some coffee?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I asked a similar question about the meaning of the word "would" in similar sentences before. My understanding was, the word "would" asks about the willingness of the listener to do something.

Now, I'm wondering whether it has a specific different meaning or implication in this sentence (I can't seem to fit that previous description in the above sentence); in other words, I'd like to know how and if the use of the word "would" distinguishes the two sentences from one another and how.

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Comment: They essentially mean the same thing. Would you like...? is a little bit more polite.

Comment: Direct questions ("do you want...?") are sometimes considered crude, abrupt, rude or disrespectful in many cultures, and the "would you like...?" form is more polite.

Comment: First, explain how you intend this differently from your other question ["Do 'would you care for some coffee?' and 'Do you care for some coffee?' have the same meaning?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214170/do-would-you-care-for-some-coffee-and-do-you-care-for-some-coffee-have-the). Second, you have modified ***two*** words between the two sentences here. *Would* becomes *do* and *like* becomes *want*. Which specific word change concerns you? It would be better to change only *one* of the words. Otherwise, we can't tell the specific area of your concern.